Nginx, подгрузить содержимое другой страницы, когда php отдает 404 код
Допустим в php скрипте, указываю
http_response_code(404)

В .htaccess, прописываю так
ErrorDocument 404 /?do=404
ErrorDocument 410 /?do=404
ErrorDocument 500 /?do=404

Как в конфиге Nginx к сайту, указать что при 404/410/500 коде, необходимо подгрузить другую страницу сайта?
Изначально прописано
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

Не понимаю как это работает, возможно для моего сайта и вовсе это не актуально. Поскольку все коды задаю в php скрипте.
Если попытаться подгрузить несуществующий файл на сайте, данный блок сработает?
В данном случаи, хотелось бы тоже отдать свою веб страницу для данных случаев...

Вы уж определитесь, несуществующий файл или php-скрипт. Если php-скрипт в принципе начал выполняться, значит он вполне существующий

В php, указываю код 404, мол данной новости больше нету. Сможет ли Nginx, узнать о том, что данная страница отдает 404, и подгрузить другой url не меняя текущий?

Раз уже два дня этот вопрос все игнорируют, напишу хоть что-нибудь — скорее всего вы хотите странного, потому что логически предполагается, что если уж php-скрипт принял на себя обработку запроса, то значит отрисовка страницы 404 тоже становится ответственностью php-скрипта а не nginx, а делать то, что хотите вы, наверно никто даже не додумывался
